# Java code android process stopped

Tags: java, android

**Solution**

I used only `setContentView(R.layout.menu);` I also needed `setContentView(R.layout.l2class);`

**Original Question**

I have loadscreen > menu > menu_2. When I choose menu_2 I have error. `My process stopped`

```
package com.lineage.goddess;


public class l2class extends Activity {

    private static final int SHOW_1 = 1;
    private static final int SHOW_2 = 2;
    private static final int SHOW_3 = 3;
    private static final int SHOW_4 = 4;
    private static final int SHOW_5 = 5;
    private static final int SHOW_6 = 6;
    private static final int SHOW_7 = 7;
    private static final int SHOW_8 = 8;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        Button act8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        act8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, wynnsummoner.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_8);
                }
            });
        Button act7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        act7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, eolhhealer.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_7);
                }
            });
        Button act6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        act6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, sigelknight.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_6);
                }
            });
        Button act5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        act5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, isenchanter.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_5);
                }
            });
        Button act4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        act4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, othelrogue.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_4);
                }
            });
        Button act3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        act3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, tirwarrior.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_3);
                }
            });
        Button act2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        act2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, yrarcher.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_2);
                }
            });
        Button act1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        act1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(l2class.this, feohwizard.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_1);
                }
            });
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case SHOW_1://case show_1

                    break;
                case SHOW_2://case show_2

                    break;
                case SHOW_3://case show_3

                    break;
                case SHOW_4://case show_4
                    break;
                case SHOW_5://case show_5
                    break;
                case SHOW_6://case show_6
                    break;
                case SHOW_7://case show_7
                    break;
                case SHOW_8://case show_8



                    break;

                }//switch
            }//if result_ok
        }//onactivityresult


    //TODO: Fill In Methods Etc.
    }//class
```

Menu 1:

```
package com.lineage.goddess;

public class menu extends Activity {

    private static final int SHOW_1 = 1;
    private static final int SHOW_2 = 2;
    private static final int SHOW_3 = 3;
    private static final int SHOW_4 = 4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        Button act4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        act4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(menu.this, l2class.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_4);
                }
            });
        Button act3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        act3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(menu.this, location.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_3);
                }
            });
        Button act2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        act2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(menu.this, help.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_2);
                }
            });
        Button act1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        act1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(menu.this, room.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_1);
                }
            });
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case SHOW_1://case show_1
                    break;
                case SHOW_2://case show_2
                    break;
                case SHOW_3://case show_3
                    break;
                case SHOW_4://case show_4
                    break;

                }//switch
            }//if result_ok
        }//onactivityresult
    }//class
```

Logcat :

```
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lineage.goddess/com.lineage.goddess.l2class}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lineage.goddess/com.lineage.goddess.l2class}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.lineage.goddess.l2class.onCreate(l2class.java:32)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-22 22:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What does [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) say?

Comment: nothing on logcat :O what does it mean ?:(

Comment: im reboot eclipse . now in logcat : 12-23 01:03:23.974: E/HdmiService(124): read audioState failed . and app dont launch :|

Comment: Something on line 32 of `l2class` is `null` and shouldn't be.

Comment: i found my mistake :       setContentView(R.layout.menu); need        setContentView(R.layout.l2class);

Comment: @user1108339 Since you figured it out, you should post an answer for the question saying how you fixed it and why it fixed it. And then accept your answer when StackOverflow allows (24 hours later or so, I think).

Comment: I have edited the question, since I dont believe that user1108339 will be back anytime sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what is 32 line in your code? As my guess the `act8` is not created properly may be its not finding the `R.id.button8`, that's the reason you are getting exception.